# Transform Javascript Array into delimited String

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a Javascript string array with values like A12, B50, C105 etc. and I want to turn it into a pipe delimited string like this: A12|B50|C105...

How could I do this? I'm using jQuery (in case that helps with some kind of builtin function).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
var pipe_delimited_string = string_array.join("|");
```

[`Array.join`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/Join.html) is a native `Array` method in Javascript which turns an array into a string, **joined** by the specified separator (which could be an empty string, one character, or multiple characters).

Answer (score 11):

No need for `jQuery`. Use `Javascripts` **join()** method. Like

```
var arr = ["A12", "C105", "B50"],
    str = arr.join('|');

alert(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript '`join`' method. Like this:
`Array1.join('|')`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For a native JavaScript array then `myArray.join('|')` will do just fine.

On the other hand, if you are using jQuery and the return value is a jQuery wrapped array then you could do something like the following (untested):

```
jQuerySelectedArray.get().join('|')
```

See this [article](http://api.jquery.com/map/#callback) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I using **lodash@4.17.10**. It's very good with array and object

```
_.join(['a', 'b', 'c'], '~');
// => 'a~b~c'
```

[Ref lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#join)

Answer (score -1):

var checked = $(':input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){return this.value}).get();
console.log(checked.join(", "));

Answer (score -1):

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
var employee = new Array(); 
employee.push("Yashwant"); 
employee.push("Dinesh"); 
employee.push("Mayur"); 
var employeeStr = employee.join("|"); 
alert('Delimited String :- ' + employeeStr); 
var employeeArray = new Array(); 
employeeArray = employeeStr.split("|"); 
for(var x=0;x<employeeArray.length;x++){ 
alert('Employee Name:- ' + employeeArray[x]); 
} 
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
```