# nodeJS for each new line in a variable, add a hyphen?

Tags: javascript, nodes

I have a single string **variable** that when logged to console looks like the following with line breaks:

```
index
project.json 
extras
```

I would like to be able to print it like:

```
-index
-project.json
-extras
```

what would be a good way to start on this? I am still in the process of learning JS, so I really have nothing to show for what I've tried, sorry.

I have tried some of the methods(`console.log('-' + files_var)`), but this does:

that does this:

```
 - index
  project.json
  extras
```

Comment: that would do this.
   -index
   project.json
   extras

Comment: it is one variable that contains multiple lines. don't know why your solution was uprooted twice..

Comment: console.log(files.split("\n").join("\n-"));

Comment: @AlexDoe add an example reproduce your issue.

Comment: Oh I see. Then you would `console.log("-" + file_name_var.replace("\r\n", "\r\n -"))`. This would add a hyphen at the start and then replace replace the linebreaks with a linebreak and hyphens.

Comment: for what reason has this question been down voted three times?

Comment: too much haters (:

Comment: `console.log("-" + file_name_var.replace("\r\n", "\r\n -"))` worked for two lines.

Comment: try replacing `\r\n` with `\n`

Comment: nope, still only adds a hyphen to two lines.

Comment: what does your js code look like?

Comment: @AlexDoe Check out my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform Javascript Array into delimited String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287314/transform-javascript-array-into-delimited-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the line breaks with a line break and a `-` using `.replace()` passing a regex `/...regex.../` and giving it a global so it replaces all instances. Remember the first string would not have a line break so we will need to add it manually.

```
console.log("-" + files_var.replace(/\n\r/g, '\n\r -'))
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qk29h7zt/2/)

Comment: @AlexDoe How do you define this `var`?

Comment: it is the result of a Mysql query.`var foo = rows[0].Index`

Comment: but there is no /n/r in the actual var's value, its just foo blah and blah. each on its own line ofc.

Comment: @AlexDoe Can you try to append it to a div and see what the string really looks like using `$('div').append(foo);`

Comment: this is all for a terminal app.